# How to sort the files in the download folder by date of download?

Tags: files, sort

How can I sort the files in my download folder in the order of the date of download?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.10, and I am using Nautilus - Files 3.10.1.

Comment: What do you use to view the content of that folder? `ls` or a graphical file manager like Nautilus?

Comment: I am using Nautilus - Files 3.10.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe Date Modified would pretty much be the same as the date downloaded. View > List > Click on Date Modified

Comment: it should be, but it is not. I just downloaded a file this morning and it says the date is 2014. However sorting by "accessed date" works.

Comment: @maxple When I download any file from Firefox or Chromium, `ls -l` shows that the timestamp on the file was updated at the time of download. This timestamp corresponds to Date Modified in the file browser. However `wget` preserves the original timestamp. When I download a file with `wget` Date Accessed does show the download date. So, my answer works if you've just downloaded from the browser. But, if you've downloaded with the browser and a tool like `wget` to a directory then Date Accessed is the best sort column to show the most recently downloaded files.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see the files (not parse the file names), you can use

```
ls -t
```

The last file printed is the eldest. To print the newest last, use

```
ls -tr
```

From `man ls`:

```
   -t     sort by modification time, newest first
   -r, --reverse
          reverse order while sorting
```

If you want to parse these file names or somehow pass them to another program, you should not use `ls` since there are [various issues](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fmywiki.wooledge.org%2FParsingLs) associated with parsing its output. Bad handling of spaces in file names is the classic problem. If you need to parse these file names, edit your question and I can provide a solution depending on what exactly you need to do.

Comment: OP wants to use Nautilus, not `ls`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster so they do. The question did not mention that when I answered.

Answer (score 2):

For me the "modified date" was wrong for newly downloaded files. Instead I am using the "accessed date" and it is correct.

Comment: and how could you do that?